# Google Cloud text-to-speech REST fetch error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, fetch, google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to call the Google Cloud text-to-speech API from javascript based browser app.
I'm getting this error response for my REST call:

```
error: Object { code: 400, message: "Empty language code.", status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT" }
```

the language code is correct according to the docs... i could be doing something else wrong if anyone can point me in the right direction?
Here is my code:

```
const config = {
      method: 'POST',
      async: true,
      crossDomain: true,
      url: "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?fields=audioContent&key="+API_KEY,
      headers: {
          "x-goog-api-key": API_KEY,
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          "cache-control": "no-cache"
      },
      processData: false,
      data: {
      'input':{
         'text':'This is a text to speak'
      },
      'voice':{
         'languageCode':'en-US',
         'name':'en-US-Standard-B'
      },
      'audioConfig':{
         'audioEncoding':'MP3'
       }
     }
}
let response = await window.fetch(config.url, config)
let data = await response.json()    
console.log("got buffer", data)
```

Comment: your request isn't sending anything in the post body.  seems like maybe you're confusing the params for `window.fetch` with `jQuery.ajax`?

Comment: hmm true. I've changed it from `data` to `body` as per [this guide](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) but now I am getting the error:
`error Object { code: 400, message: "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\n[object Object]\n ^", status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT" }
code 400
message "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\n[object Object]\n ^"
status "INVALID_ARGUMENT"`

Comment: with `window.fetch` the `body` is not transformed from a JS object to a string for you.  try `body: JSON.stringify({...})`

Comment: thanks for your help! that pointed me in the right direction